# How to disable the Excel display with SAP GUI Scripting automatically

Tags: excel, vbscript, sap-gui

I recently discovered SAP GUI Scripting. First I started to record easy transactions because I wanted to test if it is possible to execute the script on different PCs with different windows and SAP users. During the testing phase I bumped into one bigger Problem.

In my company every user has the Office Integration which allows you to display (f.e. a Profit Center Report as) an Excel Document in SAP. This display setting is saved permanently.

Now the **main problem is that if you record the script with Excel display deactivated and some other users execute the script with Excel display actived the script will not process**.

Usually I disable the Excel display setting manually by:

- clicking System -> User default -> Personal Settings -> Parameter -> Parameter value for G_RW_DOCUMENT_TYPE from XLS to 0

I tried to record this process with the SAP GUI Scripting recorder but it does not record the whole process.

It only records this

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[4]/menu[2]/menu[3]").select
```

the script does not record the change in parameter value

Is there a way (by adding a code line etc.) for automatically disabling the Excel display setting from active to inactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP GUI script recorder records the commands only in 1st mode. After the command

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[4]/menu[2]/menu[3]").select
```

opens a new mode.

But you can also start the transaction directly and remain in 1st mode.

for example:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nsu3"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Now that you know that, the problem could be solved as follows:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nsu3"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP1/tabpPARAM").select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP1/tabpPARAM/ssubMAINAREA:SAPLSUID_MAINTENANCE:1104/cntlG_PARAMETER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarButton "&FIND"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chkGS_SEARCH-EXACT_WORD").selected = true
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtGS_SEARCH-VALUE").text = "G_RW_DOCUMENT_TYPE"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chkGS_SEARCH-EXACT_WORD").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]").close

myRow = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP1/tabpPARAM/ssubMAINAREA:SAPLSUID_MAINTENANCE:1104/cntlG_PARAMETER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP1/tabpPARAM/ssubMAINAREA:SAPLSUID_MAINTENANCE:1104/cntlG_PARAMETER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").modifyCell myRow,"PARVA","0"      'instead of "XLS"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP1/tabpPARAM/ssubMAINAREA:SAPLSUID_MAINTENANCE:1104/cntlG_PARAMETER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "PARVA"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
```

Regards, ScriptMan